# Distinct items in the nested list

Tags: c#, list, distinct-values

Have this models:

```
public class VMDeliveryList  //[View-model]
{
    public List<ContractDelivery> ContractDeliveryList { get; set; }
}

public class ContractDelivery
{
    public Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public List<Delivery> DeliveryList { get; set; }
}

public class Delivery
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create foreach loop for distinct Employee.Id
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: use Distinct keyword with LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to flatten the lists and then get the `Id` with a `Select`

```
foreach(int id in viewModel.ContractDeliveryList.SelectMany(a => a.DeliveryList)
                                                .Select(b => b.Employee.Id)
                                                .Distinct() )
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have `vmDeliveryList` instance of your view model. With lambda syntax:

```
var ids = vmDeliveryList.ContractDeliveryList
                        .SelectMany(cdl => cdl.DeliveryList)
                        .Select(dl => dl.Employee.Id)
                        .Distinct();
```

Unfortunately there is no `Distinct()` method in query syntax, so you can only select all ids, and then apply distinct:

```
var allIds = from cdl in vmDeliveryList.ContractDeliveryList
             from dl in cdl.DeliverList
             select dl.Employee.Id;

var ids = allIds.Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not too familiar with the SelectMany. 
The right way for me is: 
Model.ContractDeliveryList.SelectMany(x => x.DeliveryList).Select(x => x.Employee.Id).Distinct()